# ¿Por qué el contador se va disminuyendo en este codigo?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int resuelve(int anc, int larg,int cont);
int main() {
    int anc, larg;
    int cont = 0;
    cin >> anc;
    cin >> larg;

    while (anc != 0 && larg != 0) {


        cout << resuelve(anc,larg,cont) << endl;
        cin >> anc >> larg;
    }
    return 0;
}

int resuelve(int anc, int larg,int cont) {

    if (anc < 10 || larg < 10) return cont;
    else {
        if (anc >= larg) {
            cont++;
            anc = anc - larg;
            resuelve(anc, larg, cont);
        }
        else  {
            cont++;
            larg = larg - anc;
            resuelve(anc, larg, cont);
        }

    }
    return cont;
}
```

cuando pongo por ejemplo 297 y 210 el resultado que deseo es 7, pero al hacer la última recursión se vuelve a meter dentro de la función y va restandole 1 a cont, no sé por qué

anc y larg son medidas de un folio imaginario. Se trata de contar cuántos cuadrados puedo hacer desde ese folio imaginario. Lo que he intentado ha sido distinguir cual de los dos es el mayor,si el ancho o el largo. Al mayor se le resta el menor y si al hacer esa resta ninguno de los dos es menor que 10 aumento el contador de cuadrados a 1,si no, devuelvo el contador que llevo hasta ahora.

Comment: Tu pregunta no es clara, por ejemplo ¿que entrada le proporcionas?, ¿Que salida deseas y que salida obtienes?

Comment: con 297 y 210 quiero obtener 7 y siempre obtengo uno, como que al hacer la ultima recursion se vuelve a meter y va disminuyendo el contador

Comment: Edita tu pregunta, explica que desea hacer el algoritmo, da mas detalles, lee las reglas de [ask], nosotros no estamos en tu cabeza y no entendemos lo que deseas hacer.

Comment: La implementacion de tu algoritmo no es recursivo,  no usas la salida de resuelve. la funcion `resuelve` se ejecuta infinitamente pero no recursivamente.

Comment: Aparte del código deberías incluir que es lo que hace tu programa. Por qué te debería salir 7 al poner 297 y 210?

Comment: gracias, ya he intentado explicarlo algo más

Comment: Podrias mostrar tu pseudocodigo.

Comment: No tengo la solución al problema, pero me gustaría comentar un par de cosas sobre tu código. La función resuelve retorna un valor de tipo `int` pero nunca lo utilizas en el `main`. Tus variables `anc` y `larg` no son muy descriptivas que digamos, no sé cuál es el problema de escribir `ancho` y `largo`, respectivamente. Por último, deberías indicarle al usuario que ingrese esas variables usando, por ejemplo: `cout << "Ingrese el ancho: "`, y de manera similar para el largo.

Answer (score 3):

Supongamos la siguiente llamada:

```
resuelve(297,210,0);
```

Esta llamada devuelve `1` ¿por qué? Veamos:

```
int resuelve(int anc, int larg,int cont) { // <<--- 1

    if (anc < 10 || larg < 10) return cont; // <<--- 2
    else {
        if (anc >= larg) {
            cont++; // <<--- 3
            anc = anc - larg;
            resuelve(anc, larg, cont);
        }
        else  {
            cont++; // <<--- 3
            larg = larg - anc;
            resuelve(anc, larg, cont);
        }

    }
    return cont; // <<--- 4
}
```

1. `cont` vale 0
2. Si cualquiera de los dos argumentos (`anc` o `larg`) fuese menor de 10 devolvería `cont`, que tal y como se indica en el punto anterior, vale `0`.
3. En caso contrario, `cont` se incrementa en una unidad, es decir, `cont=1`.
4. Devuelves `cont`, es decir, `1`.

El problema es que el programa no hace nada con los valores devueltos por las llamadas recursivas... La solución en este punto es tan sencilla como esto:

```
int resuelve(int anc, int larg,int cont) {

    if (anc < 10 || larg < 10) return cont;
    else {
        if (anc >= larg) {
            cont++;
            anc = anc - larg;
            return resuelve(anc, larg, cont);
        //  ^^^^^^
        }
        else  {
            cont++;
            larg = larg - anc;
            return resuelve(anc, larg, cont);
        //  ^^^^^^
        }
    }
    // return cont;
}
```

Esta otra también serviría:

```
int resuelve(int anc, int larg,int cont) {

    if (anc < 10 || larg < 10) return cont;
    else {
        if (anc >= larg) {
            cont++;
            anc = anc - larg;
            cont = resuelve(anc, larg, cont);
        //  ^^^^^^
        }
        else  {
            cont++;
            larg = larg - anc;
            cont = resuelve(anc, larg, cont);
        //  ^^^^^^
        }

    }
    return cont;
}
```

Aunque por limpieza yo preferiría esta otra:

```
int resuelve(int anc, int larg,int cont) {

    if (anc >= 10 && larg >= 10)
    {
        cont++;
        if (anc >= larg)
            anc = anc - larg;
        else
            larg = larg - anc;

        cont = resuelve(anc, larg, cont);
    }
    return cont;
}
```